# How to access data from a transitive relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Lets say I have 3 tables defined within SQLAlchemy: `Task`, `Job`, `Log` where `Task` defines some kind of task that can be executed, `Job` defines the concrete values of an executed task and `Log` stores some information about every execution. So each Log knows its job ID and each job knows its task ID:

```
class Task(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    # ...

    jobs = relationship("Job", backref="task")


class Job(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'job'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("task.id"), nullable=False)
    # ...

    logs = relationship("Log", backref="job")


class Log(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'name'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job.id"), nullable=False)
    # ...
```

In our GUI we list all `Log` entries in order so our costumers can review them. However we need to filter them now and we want to filter them by task name. My naive approach was a new method in our `LogDAO`

```
class DAO(object):
    def __init__(self, session, model):
        """ :param session: The database session that is used for data access
            :param model: The db model class
        """
        self.session = session
        self.model = model


class LogDAO(DAO):
    def __init__(self, session):
        super(LogDAO, self).__init__(session, Log)

    # ...
    def with_task_name(task_name):
        self.session.query(self.model.job.task.name == task_name)
```

`self.model.job` exists but `self.model.job.task` does not. Is there any other elegant way to filter `Log` entries by `Task` name?

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution:

```
class LogDAO(DAO):
    # ...
    def with_task_name(task_name):
        return self.session.query(Log)
            .join(Log.job)
            .join(Job.task)
            .filter(Task.name == task_name)
```